# nuxt.js image not show when push refresh button

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using nuxtjs and I would like to use  with url that come from $store

in *page/me/index.vue* is

```
<template>
<div>
<img :src="user.avatar.url" />
<span>{{user.name}}</span>
</div>
</template>

<script>

  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    head () {
      return {
        title: 'Me - personal page',
        meta: [
        ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      user () { return this.$store.state.user }
    }
  }
</script>
```

but after I push refresh button on browser it show

[image]

I try to delete tag , everything work fine (I can see user.name)

Please help me how to solve this problem.

Regards.

Comment: `I try to delete tag , everything work fine (I can see user.name)` Does that mean `user.name` is working correctly on page refresh, just `user.avatar.url` is not working on page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Your store will be deleted on refresh. So this is expected behaviour.
You have to save your state somehow, to persist it.
The two most popular options are localstorage or a session cookie. With nuxtjs a cookie will be more suitable.
The most used plugin for this is [vuex-persiststate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate).
The following is taken from their documentation:
Sample code:

```
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const store = new Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      getState: (key) => Cookies.getJSON(key),
      setState: (key, state) => Cookies.set(key, state, { expires: 3, secure: true })
    })
  ]
})
```

You need to install [`js-cookie`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) for the above code to work.
Please refer to the official documentation for more details: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate